# Not able to connect to mysql via php script , but can login to phpmyadmin in LAMP UBUNTU

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, lampp

I am trying to connect to mysql using PHP in ubuntu LAMP. I can login to phpmyadmin , but not able to connect using php code. The code was working well in XAMPP .

I am using the following code

```
 $con=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","myusername","mypassword");
        if (!$con)
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

But it shows the following error

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` means the password is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your replay , but listen password is correct , I can login to phpmyadmin with same credentials.

Comment: May be your phpmyadmin is connecting somewhere else.. But, again, this message tells only that either there is no root, or the password is incorrect. Look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Comment: I recommend you at least consider changing from mysql_* functions to mysqli or PDO_Mysql. mysql_* functions have been deprecated.

Comment: Btw, did you use for `myusername` root account?

Comment: Yes I have used root as my username

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 (that i know of) posible solutions to this depending on the problem.

1. There is a firewall in ubuntu that you need to open, you do this by granting access in IPtables.

   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
   And now we should be able to login to our server from our local machine:

   mysql -h255.112.324.12 -uroot -pMyPASSWORD
2. You need to grant access to mysql: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159053/mysql-server-not-accessible-from-remote-machine

   as root, open your /etc/mysql/my.cnf with your favorite editor
   look for the [mysqld] section, and in there for the bind-address keyword. This usually is set to        127.0.0.1 -- change that to match your "normal" IP-address
   save the file, and reload the service (e.g. using service mysql restart)
3. Last but not least you need to give remote access in mysql:

   GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyPASSWORD';

Source: http://web.archive.org/web/20120930214828/http://chosencollective.com/technology/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql + Many sleepless nights.